# Unpacking? strange commas in python

Tags: python, iterable-unpacking

I was looking at some code that returns the second largest element of a list and came across a weird use of commas. Hopefully someone can explain it to me:

it is the

```
m1, m2 = x, m1
```

part of the following code:

```
def second_largest(numbers):
    m1, m2 = None, None

    for x in numbers:
        if x >= m1:
            m1, m2 = x, m1
        elif x > m2:
           m2 = x

    return m2
```

What is getting assigned what in this if statement?

Comment: `x` is getting assigned to `m1` and `m1` to `m2`, in unison.

Comment: This is poor coding for the exact reason why it wasn't entirely clear to you what was happening here at first glance. Although it's a line saver, it's less apparent what you're trying to do and makes your code harder to read.

Comment: I'd say what makes it hard to read is the variable names `m1` and `m2`. The multiple assignment is standard Python.

Comment: Also, comparing numbers to `None` is a really bad idea.

Comment: Multiple assignments are standard in python, I agree, but not like that, more like `x, y, z = some_tuple`. If you're setting two variables to two other variables I was taught it's improper to try to squish it all into one line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially, the tuple `(m1,m2)` is recieving the values in the tuple `(x,m1)`.  After the statement `m1` will have the old value of `x` and `m2` will have the old value of `m1`.  Example:

```
>>> x = 2
>>> y = 3
>>> z = 4
>>> x,y = y,z
>>> x
3
>>> y
4
```

The tuple `(x,m1)` is created before any assignments are made.  As a result, this syntax is often used for swapping two variables.  For example, `x,y = y,x` will swap the values in `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

This code: `m1, m2 = x, m1` means storing the value of `x` to `m1`, and value of `m1` to `m2`.